# display data based on uiswitch state

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to display data based on if the user has selected a switch. the user will have he ability to select either one or two switches to either both on or one or other on. Data will then be displayed according to the state of the switch.

I have managed to get this to load however its only displaying data from the dare array in the plist file and it dosnt matter which state the switch is in it displays dare not truth or both.

```
- (IBAction)shownext:(id)sender {
    if (!self.plistArray) {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                          @"data" ofType:@"plist"];  
        NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"truthonoff"] isEqualToString:@"YES"] && [[defaults objectForKey:@"dareonoff"] isEqualToString:@"YES"]  ) {
            NSDictionary *plistDict1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
            NSArray * plistArray1 = plistDict1[@"truth"];
            NSDictionary *plistDict2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
            NSArray *plistArray2 = plistDict2[@"dare"];
            self.plistArray = [[plistArray1 arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:plistArray2] mutableCopy];

        } else if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"truthonoff"] isEqualToString:@"YES"] ) {
            NSDictionary *plistDict3 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
            NSArray *plistArray3 = plistDict3[@"truth"] ;
            self.plistArray = [plistArray3 mutableCopy];
            NSLog(@"%@", plistArray);
        } else ([[defaults objectForKey:@"dareonoff"] isEqualToString:@"YES"] ); {
            NSDictionary *plistDict4 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
            NSMutableArray *plistArray4 = plistDict4[@"dare"];
            self.plistArray = [plistArray4 mutableCopy];
            NSLog(@"%@", plistArray);
        }
    }
}



 -(void)stateSwitched:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *tswitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject: tswitch.isOn ? @"YES" : @"NO" forKey:@"truthonoff"];

    [defaults synchronize];
}

-(void)stateSwitcheddare:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *tswitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject: tswitch.isOn ? @"YES" : @"NO" forKey:@"dareonoff"];

    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

THis is my code for setting the object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use boolForKey instead of objectForKey. And in the other hand, why does the else have a condition?:

```
if ([defaults boolForKey:@"truthonoff"] && [defaults boolForKey:@"dareonoff"]) {
     // Both true 
} else if ([defaults boolForKey:@"truthonoff"] && ![defaults boolForKey:@"dareonoff"]) {
     // truthonoff true, dareonoff false
} else if (![defaults boolForKey:@"truthonoff"] && [defaults boolForKey:@"dareonoff"]) {
     // truthonoff false, dareonoff true
} else {
     // Both false
}
```

Make sure to do two things when you store boolean values in the NSUserStandardDefaults:

1. Use setBool setter: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"a_key"];
2. Remember to synchronize the standardUserDefaults to save the values.

Comment: Hey sorry for late reply been out of signal. I have given this a go and am getting error i think it may be because im not implimenting the boolforkey correct can you advice? the error is on the first if statement?

Comment: -(void)stateSwitched:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *tswitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject: tswitch.isOn ? @"YES" : @"NO" forKey:@"truthonoff"];
    
    [defaults synchronize];
}